# ClassCastException on Updating to Selenium 3.4

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, qaf

We are using QAF for functional test automation. We recently upgraded selenium version from 3.3.1 to 3.4.0 and it started giving following error at some places.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebElement
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:366)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.findElement(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:169)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver.findElement(QAFExtendedWebDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:178)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
```

My observation is, it works fine if we don't have driver.findBy(BY) statement. for test purpose in one place i tried driver.findBy(String) instead of driver.findBy(BY) and it worked fine. But i don't know how many places team had used above method.

Below is the test which reproduces error:

```
@Test
    public void test1() {
        get("/");
        QAFExtendedWebDriver driver = getDriver();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("do something");
    }
```

Because of this issue we have to revert back on selenium version 3.3.1. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of method visibility change in one of the selenium class. It may get resolved by [fix-4279](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/4279) in next version.

It is get resolved with qaf-2.1.12-RC2